# How to detect tablet layout and open two layout fragments on the screen (Like master detail fragments)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, tablet

I have two fragments. Once I start the app First fragment opens. I open second fragment when i click on any item inside my recyclerview in the first fragment. I want to show both fragments on the screen same time when it's a tablet(Like master-detail layout). Can I do it from a fragment? I know that fragments live inside activity. But is there a way to detect that app is running on the tablet from a fragment?

I have activity_main.xml which has one Framelayout where I programmatically replace my first fragment. And I have four other activity_main.xml (w600dp,w600dp-land,w720dp,w720dp-land) layouts for tablets that have two Framelayouts.

Answer (score 2):

in res directory create new folder values-w820dp

create dimens.xml file there inside dimens.xml write this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<resources>

<!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined inres/values    /dimens.xml (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->


<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>

<bool name="is_tablet">true</bool>

</resources>
```

inside your dimens.xml file in your values folder write this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<resources>

<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->


<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>

<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

<bool name="is_tablet">false</bool>

</resources>
```

in your activity get "is_tablet" values from dimens.xml value , if it is true it means it is a tablet , else it is not this is the example code which i used

```
public class FragmentsFirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IFragments{

public static final String DEBUG = "Tutorials";

FragmentsFirstActivityFragment mFirstFragment;
FragmentsSecondActivityFragment mSecondFragment;

boolean is_tablet = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragments_first_activity);

    is_tablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_tablet);

    Log.d(DEBUG, "Is Tablet: " + is_tablet);


    mFirstFragment = new FragmentsFirstActivityFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.first_fragment, mFirstFragment).commit();

    if (is_tablet) {
        mSecondFragment = new FragmentsSecondActivityFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.second_fragment, mSecondFragment).commit();
    }
}


@Override
public void onButtonClicked(String message) {

    if(is_tablet) {

    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FragmentsSecondActivity.class).putExtra("message", message));
    }
}
 }
```

hope this helps

Comment: So I need to create another activity that will handle if it's a tablet layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use master detail fragment to show two fragments in one layout and to separate tablet and phone use 

`if (Common.IsTablet(Context))
{
}`

```
public static bool IsTablet(Context context)
        {
            return ((context.Resources.Configuration.ScreenLayout & ScreenLayout.SizeMask) >= ScreenLayout.SizeLarge) ||
                   ((context.Resources.Configuration.ScreenLayout & ScreenLayout.SizeMask) >= ScreenLayout.SizeXlarge);

        } // to detect whether device is tablet
```